# Ripple effect not working in relative layout with image

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin, android-recyclerview, material-design

Ripple effect is not working with the below code! Using the below relative layout as item in recycler view. Building with Xamarin platform.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativelayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:paddingBottom="1dp"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bugImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" 
        android:src="@drawable/grey_small"
        android:clickable="false"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textBugName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/bugImage"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/bugImage"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/bugImage"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="Klebsiella pneumoniae"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="145dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:shadowColor="#000000"
        android:shadowDx="0"
        android:shadowDy="0"
        android:shadowRadius="25"
        android:clickable="false"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textBugCount"
        android:layout_width="135dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/bugImage"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/bugImage"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/bugImage"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="234"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:padding="10dp" 
        android:shadowColor="#000000"
        android:shadowDx="0"
        android:shadowDy="0"
        android:shadowRadius="25"
        android:clickable="false"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I have already tried this `android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"` and it didn't work!

How to fix this? I tested it on api 22.

Comment: More info .... please

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what you're trying to accomplish with this (i.e. setting foreground):

```
android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

Try this:

```
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

though I use a custom drawable to have control over coloring, as shown here:

Set the *background* on your RelativeLayout `android:background="@drawable/mybackground"`

in res/drawable, **mybackground.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/disabledBackground" />
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@color/colorAccent" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/listBackground" />
</selector>
```

in res/drawable-v21, **mybackground.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple android:color="@color/disabledBackground" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
    <selector>
        <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/disabledBackground" />
        <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@color/colorAccent" />
        <item android:drawable="@color/listBackground" />
    </selector>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

Here you've specified the ripple effect, supported on platforms v21+.  You can adjust the colors and states to your needs, *disabledBackground*, *colorAccent*, *listBackground* are just examples of named color attributes

Comment: It works but the problem is before user even notices ripple, view is changed. Long click shows ripple but normal click doesn't show ripple unlike WhatsApp. In WhatsApp, it shows ripple then view is changed however I am unable to achieve this functionality despite that I have added these line of codes.

Answer (score 1):

With a RelativeLayout as a root view you should set the native ripple with background="" instead of foreground=""

Or you may try to implement a cardview which will properly respond to foreground=""

Answer (score 1):

> android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"

works only for frame layout.

use

> android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"

or it is better to use:

> android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"

if you are using compat library

Answer (score 0):

Just add android:onClick="add on click listener here" and  android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground" to your layout where you need a ripple effect. It worked for me.